# uwsgi/nginx doesn't respond until subprocess is done

Tags: python, django, nginx, subprocess, uwsgi

I have server with nginx the passes http trafic to uwsgi runnig my django app.
the django view I'm calling is creating a subprocess that runs the following test.sh bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo hello
sleep 10
echo morning
```

for some reason I am not getting the 200 response from the view until the bash is done, i.e. "morning" is printed, although subprocess supposed to create a thread that run in parallel.

While trying to debug this issue I noticed that if I cURL locally from server while running django directly with `python manage.py runserver` or when running uwsgi with `http=127.0.0.1:8000` I get the 200 response before the "morning" print as expected.

Any ideas why with socket=127.0.0.1:8000 and nginx it behaves different?

my nginx is configured to pass http trafic to django:

```
upstream django {
server 127.0.0.1:8000; # for a web port socket (we'll use this first)
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /api/ {
            uwsgi_pass  django;
            include     /path_to/uwsgi_params; # the uwsgi_params file you installed
    }
}
```

my uwsgi ini:

```
[uwsgi]
socket=127.0.0.1:8000
module=my_module.wsgi:application
chdir=/project_dir
master=true
vacuum=true
logger=file:/log_path
stats=/tmp/uwsgi_stats.socket
single interpreter=true
```

and my view.py is:

```
from subprocess import Popen
from rest_framework import views
from rest_framework.response import Response

class TestApi(views.APIView):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        Popen(["/opt/test.sh"])
        return Response({})
```

Comment: What makes you think this is abnormal? WSGI is synchronous.

Comment: so how come when running uwsgi with http=127.0.0.1:8000 (instrad of scokect it works? and in general how is one should implement the above asynchronously? I am trying to make my api run a script asynchronously since it takes a while and doesn't affect the api result

Comment: It should not behave differently, that is odd. And in theory this should work since you're not waiting for output (I read that too fast initially), however this may be burried in the guts of Django as it is trying to close all file handles on end of response. Sorry, this should work.